# How to make vertical tabview scrollable? PrimeNG

Tags: css, angular, primeng

So far I achieved vertical tabview, but now I am having a problem to make it scrollable (vertical).
This is css I am using to make tabview vertical and scrollable:

```
:host ::ng-deep .orientation-right{
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    max-height: 800px;
}

:host ::ng-deep .p-tabview-nav {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

This is what I got:

[image]

When I set height to list it goes to multiple columns, not staying in one column like it should.
Any suggestions?